# Numeric conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There are several ways to convert a string to a number (integer) in JavaScript.

```
let number = "100"

+number
number*1
parseInt(number)
Number(number)

// and so on...
```

What is the difference between these methods and when to use them?

Comment: `+`, `Number` and `*1` are all exactly equivalent.

Comment: Use `parseInt(number, 10)`. Tricks like `+` and `*1` are just trying to save characters; be explicit and intent-revealing instead.

Comment: First two equivalent. `parseInt` allows invalid number strings and stops at first non-numeric, `Number(s)` doesn't.

Comment: @DaveNewton ugh I forgot that `parseInt` will take as much number as it can! That's a good point.